# Let X be an infinite Hausdorff space. Suppose, x is the limit point of $A$ $\subset$ $X$), s.t. x is a limit point of A.

Tags: general-topology

Question: Let X be an infinite Hausdorff space. Suppose x is a limit point of A which is a subset of X (or x is the limit point of $A$ $\subset$ $X$), s.t. x is a limit point of A. Then for every open set U $\in$ x, U contains infinitely many points of A.

How to do this?

If A is the limit point of $A$ $\subset$ $X$, then we know that there $\forall$ U open in A, U $\in$ x, s.t. U $\cap$ A = $\emptyset$, and from definition of Hausdorff spaces, we can say that $\forall$ different x,y $\in$ X, $\exists$ U, V $\in$ T, s.t. $x \in U$ ^ $y \in V$ ^ $U \cap V$ = $\emptyset$. But I am not sure how to bring the concept of infinite Hausdorff space to show that U contains infinitely many points of A. 
Need help here, appreciate your help and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A \subseteq X$ and $x$ is a limit point of $A$, and $X$ is Hausdorff.

This means that for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $U$ intersects $A \setminus \{x\}$.

Suppose now that $U \cap A$ were finite for some open $U$.
Fact: in a Hausdorff space all finite sets are closed. (In fact the latter is equivalent to $X$ being $T_1$ and Hausdorff implies $T_1$) so $V:= X\setminus ((U \cap A) \cup \{x\})$ is open and contains $x$. Now $(V \cap U) \cap A \subseteq \{x\}$ : $y \in (V \cap U) \cap A$ implies $y \in U \cap A$ but as $y \in V$ too, $y=x$. This shows that the open neighbourhood $U \cap V$ of $x$ witnesses that $x$ is *not* a limit point of $A$, contrary to assumption.

So $U \cap A$ can never be finite, for $U$ an open neighbourhood of $x$.

We only use Hausdorff mildly; $T_1$ is all we need.

Comment: Can you please explain wat neighborhood means? I think I know that it means that there is an open set or there exist an open set $U$ of x. Does NBH mean that its an open set named U that contains x?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is consufing. I will assume that $x$ is a point of $A$ which is a limit point in the subspace topology.

If $U$ is open in $X$ and contains $x \in A$ then $A \cap U$ is an open set in $A$ containing $x$. Hence it contains inf infinitely many points of $A$.

Comment: How can I descriptively explain this proof? Can I say that $A \cap U$ is not equal to $\emptyset$ since it is open? I am sure if I say this, my prof wont accept this proof. He wants us to explain each and every tiny things of a proof properly.